# Stopping player from spamming movement keys which causes glitches

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a script for the player movement in c#. Whenever the player presses A or D, it moves him/her to the left or right by 12 units and when the player presses W or S, it moves him/her up or down by 12 units. My script works fine, but if a person starts to spam all of the keys at once, it glitches out and the player object is not in line with the level anymore. I want to have the script check if there a movement is currently happening before executing the movement on the keypress. Here is my script:

```
void Update () {

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * ForwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A) && side > maxSideLeft) {
        MoveObjectTo(this.transform, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x - 12, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z + 10), movementSpeed);
        side -= 1;
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D) && side < maxSideRight) {
        MoveObjectTo(this.transform, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x + 12, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z + 10), movementSpeed);
        side += 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W) && level < maxLevelHeight) {
        MoveObjectTo(this.transform, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y + 12, this.transform.position.z + 10), movementSpeed);
        level += 1;
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.S) && level > minLevelHeight) {
        MoveObjectTo(this.transform, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y - 12, this.transform.position.z + 10), movementSpeed);
        level -= 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.R) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Scene1");
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}


private void MoveObjectTo(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 targetPosition, float moveSpeed)
{
    StopCoroutine(MoveObject(objectToMove, targetPosition, moveSpeed));
    StartCoroutine(MoveObject(objectToMove, targetPosition, moveSpeed));
}

public static IEnumerator MoveObject(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 targetPosition, float moveSpeed)
{
    float currentProgress = 0;
    Vector3 cashedObjectPosition = objectToMove.transform.position;

    while (currentProgress <= 1)
    {
        currentProgress += moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        objectToMove.position = Vector3.Lerp(cashedObjectPosition, targetPosition, currentProgress);

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `isMoving` variable for this. Don't move if the variable is `true`. Move if it is `false`. When the coroutine is done running set `isMoving` back to `false`. Also, I can't tell why `MoveObject` function is `static`. I removed the `static` keyword from it.

```
bool isMoving = false;

void Update()
{

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * ForwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && side > maxSideLeft)
    {
        MoveObjectTo(this.transform, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x - 12, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z + 10), movementSpeed);
        side -= 1;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && side < maxSideRight)
    {
        MoveObjectTo(this.transform, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x + 12, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z + 10), movementSpeed);
        side += 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && level < maxLevelHeight)
    {
        MoveObjectTo(this.transform, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y + 12, this.transform.position.z + 10), movementSpeed);
        level += 1;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && level > minLevelHeight)
    {
        MoveObjectTo(this.transform, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y - 12, this.transform.position.z + 10), movementSpeed);
        level -= 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene1");
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}


private void MoveObjectTo(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 targetPosition, float moveSpeed)
{
    //Don't do anything Object is already moving
    if (isMoving)
    {
        return;
    }
    //If not moving set isMoving to true
    isMoving = true;
    StartCoroutine(MoveObject(objectToMove, targetPosition, moveSpeed));
}

public IEnumerator MoveObject(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 targetPosition, float moveSpeed)
{
    float currentProgress = 0;
    Vector3 cashedObjectPosition = objectToMove.transform.position;

    while (currentProgress <= 1)
    {
        currentProgress += moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        objectToMove.position = Vector3.Lerp(cashedObjectPosition, targetPosition, currentProgress);

        yield return null;
    }
    //Done moving. Set isMoving to false
    isMoving = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I just didn't know where I should set the booleans to active and false so I could make it work.

Comment: I did. I just did that for you in my answer. Just copy and replace it with your code.

Comment: Yeah, I did that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to check to see if the user has completed their lerp before lerping to some new position. In that case, you will want to prevent your player from moving again until your `currentProgress` variable is equal to 1. Thus, use a simple boolean callback and prevent calling the Corouting until that callback is true. Your `MoveObject` function:

```
public static IEnumerator MoveObject(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 targetPosition, float moveSpeed, System.Action<bool> callBack)
{
    float currentProgress = 0;
    Vector3 cashedObjectPosition = objectToMove.transform.position;

    while (currentProgress <= 1)
    {
        currentProgress += moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        objectToMove.position = Vector3.Lerp(cashedObjectPosition, targetPosition, currentProgress);

        yield return null;

        if (currentProgress >= 1)
            callBack(true);
    }
}
```

Then you can change your `MoveObjectTo` function to read this callback:

```
private void MoveObjectTo(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 targetPosition, float moveSpeed)
{
    if (canCallCoroutine)
    {
        canCallCoroutine = false;
        StartCoroutine(MoveObject(objectToMove, targetPosition, moveSpeed, finished =>
            {
                if (finished != null)
                {
                    if (finished)
                        canCallCoroutine = true;
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the canCallCoroutine come from? Is it a bool declared in the beginning?

Comment: yeah it's just some global boolean variable. Sorry for not making that clearer